# Find a recursive algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, performance, recursion, complexity-theory

I am not sure if I am calculating the complexity of a recursive algorithm correctly.

Could you please check it and tell if I am correct.

```
  public static long gcdMultiple(long[] input) {
        long result = input[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) result = gcd(result, input[i]);
        return result;
    }

    public static final long gcd(long q, long p) {
        if (q == 0) return p;
        if (p == 0) return q;

        // p and q even
        if ((p & 1) == 0 && (q & 1) == 0) return gcd(p >> 1, q >> 1) << 1;

            // p is even, q is odd
        else if ((p & 1) == 0) return gcd(p >> 1, q);

            // p is odd, q is even
        else if ((q & 1) == 0) return gcd(p, q >> 1);

            // p and q odd, p >= q
        else if (p >= q) return gcd((p - q) >> 1, q);

            // p and q odd, p < q
        else return gcd(p, (q - p) >> 1);
    }
```

First function `gcdMultiple` has the complexity equal to `O(n)`, because it iterates `n` times where `n` is equal to number of items in the array passed to the function.
Second function is much complex, I really cannot figure out how to find its complexity, but I assume it is about `O(nlog(n))`
So the common complexity is `nLog(n) * n = n^2log(n) = n^2` 
Am I right ?

Please explain how to calculate complexity correctly in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner function is [binary GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm), and its complexity is `O(log(p) + log(q))`.
You can follow the link for details, but basically, at least one of the arguments is halved in `O(1)` steps, so no more than `log(p) + log(q)` steps are required to bring both `p` and `q` down to 1.

The outer loop runs `n` times, so basically, we have the upper bound `O(n * log(c))` where `c` is the maximum possible element in the `input` array.

For an input consisting of `n` copies of the number 2<sup>k</sup>, the number of elementary operations is indeed `n * k`.
Note that `k` is proportional to `log(c)`.
So the bound is exact.

---

> Second function is much complex, I really cannot figure out how to find its complexity, but I assume it is about O(nlog(n))

As for your note above, and I assume `n` is the length of input: there is no `n` in the inner function in the first place.
Both arguments are just `long`s and don't depend on the number of inputs.

---

And as a side note, if we used [Euclid's GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) in place of Stein's GCD as the inner function, I believe the overall complexity would go from `O(n * log(c))` down to just `O(n + log(c))`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. So basically we can ignore `O(log(p) + log(q))` and just take `O(n * log(c)) `as overall complexity ?

Comment: @bxfvgekd `log(c)` is just the asymptotic upper bound of `log(p) + log(q)` for all possible `p` and `q`.